# Amazon Cognito - Require phone verification - but not MFA. Is is possible?

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

We want the phone number to be verified before the user signs up, but we don't require MFA - meaning the user should be able to sign in with just email address and password.
Cognito requires MFA to be enabled for phone verification. There is no way out of it. Is my understanding correct?
[image]

Comment: Verification during Signup doesn't have anything to do with MFA.

Comment: @Claies - I get that, but phone verification without enabling MFA isn't allowed in cognito and that's my query.

Comment: My understanding, however, is that MFA has 3 possible options;  `Required`, `Optional`, or `Off`.  Since verification requires SMS, once you enable SMS, you cannot set MFA to `Off`.  You can, however, set it to `Optional`, which will allow the End User to decide if they want to use MFA, since they already gave you their Phone Number.  You **do not** have to set the MFA policy to `Required` for verification to work, nor do you have to turn MFA on at all if you are not doing SMS (text).

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It is possible because MFA and verification are two different things.
You could keep MFA off and enable verification by selecting either one of two or both **email** and **phone number** which helps you for **confirm user** and recovery functionality like **forgot password** etc. If you are not verifying the user after signup, you will not able to sign in and get access / Id token, sign in is allowed after "confirm user".

You could go for MFA option as well, if you want to setup an advance security for your users.

Comment: I get that phone verification and MFA are two different things. But, without enabling MFA, phone verification isn't allowed in cognito and that's my question.

Comment: You may have set MFA required while creating user pool. Need to update/ create new user pool without MFA, I'm also working on the same thing. It works for me.

Comment: I have updated my question with an image. I will appreciate if you can tell me how you do phone verification via congnito without enabling MFA

Comment: Upper section i.e MFA which is hidden / not captured in your image where you have to select "off" check for MFA not "required" .

Comment: yes, I am using javascript sdk. MFA is indeed turned off by me and hence the message.

Comment: This question is 3 years old, yet I'm facing same issue now. Have you been able to solve it somehow?